# Why mixing + and cast does not produce an error in "+(int)+(long)-1"?

Tags: java

Why does this print 1?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        System.out.println((byte)+(short)-(int)+(long)-1);
    }
}
```

Can we mix casting and `+,-` unary operators? I know that we can do casting multiple times, but why doesn't putting `+ ,-` unary operators in between produce an error?

Comment: These `+` and `-` are unary ones.

Comment: Read operations from right to left.

Comment: I thought that the questions "[explain what this code does](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253894/1090562)" are off-topic here. What makes this one an exception?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions

Comment: @SalvadorDali chaining title should make it more reasonable.

Comment: @SalvadorDali The users involved in that Q&A don't see the accepted answer there as a blanket rule. (Read the comments.)

Comment: @SalvadorDali This is a single short line of code that focuses on a specific interaction between language constructs. It's about as specific as you can get, so the "too broad" mentioned in the Meta post doesn't really apply.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You are not adding nor substracting. Those + and - operators are unary sign operators.

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) at **The Unary Operators** section.

The sequence at stake:

```
(byte)+(short)-(int)+(long)-1
```

is evaluated from right to left like this:

> the initial value is -1
>   casting to long (which is still -1)
>   unary + sign (still -1)
>   casting to int (still -1)
>   unary - sign (now the value is 1)
>   so on (the value remains 1 until the end)

Answer (score 39):

These `+` and `-` are unary ones.

More specifically, it is in fact:

```
System.out.println((byte) (+((short) (-((int) (+((long) -1)))))));
```

Comment: Woah there, since when did Java become Lisp? :)

Comment: @Doorknob - That's no where near enough parenthesis to be compared to Lisp : P

Comment: The asker appears to already be aware that those are unary operators, which makes this answer not seem particularly useful, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Dukeling He edited his question after I answered. Originally "signs" is used instead of "unary operators".

Answer (score 12):

if you remove all casting from your example, because in this case it will do nothing

> `System.out.println((byte)+(short)-(int)+(long)-1);`

will become

> `System.out.println(      +       -     +      -1);`

now you can see that just the operators are still there and because **minus and minus are plus** your result will be 1

basically you can think of it like:

```
var mylong  = +(long)-1;      <- -1
var myint   = -(int)mylong;   <-  1
var myshort = +(short)myint;  <-  1
var mybyte  =  (byte)myshort; <-  1
```

Comment: The addition/subtraction example is misleading. No addition/subtraction is involved in the example.

Comment: @SalmanA, it's doubly misleading, because there's no addition/substraction taking place in the example.

Answer (score 7):

> I know we can do casting multiple times. But putting + ,- unary operators in between doesn't give error?

It is simply a consequence of the consistency of Java's grammar. When you write

```
+ 1
```

what you actually wrote is a *unary numeric expression* which decomposes into two parts:

1. the unary plus operator: `+`
2. a *numeric expression*, in this case the `int` literal `1`.

Another example of a numeric expression is a *cast expression* (also unary):

```
(int) 1
```

Therefore you can substitute this for the original `1` above:

```
+ (int) 1
```

Repeating the same consistent process we can end up with a nested unary expression of arbitrary complexity. To return to your key question:

> why?

Because Java would actually need a specific rule *against* such expressions.